# Runtime error while executing commands in PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++, postgresql-9.5

We have a custom installer which installs several components, along with that, it executes series of SQL commands for PostgreSQL 9.5 database. At one of the systems, following error was generated (this was shown in a pop-up box having title: *Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library*)

```
Runtime Error!
Program: <PostgreSQL install path>\bin\psql.exe
R6016
-not enough space for thread data.
```

Once the button 'Ok' was clicked, the installation went ahead and was successful. The software appears to work just fine after the installation. I read about this issue at links: [link1](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160228050011.10543.11794@wrigleys.postgresql.org), [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d509d9f9.aspx), [link3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/126709/prb-error-on-win32s-r6016---not-enough-space-for-thread-data#%2Fen-us%2Fkb%2F126709). But could not determine whether that error caused any damage etc.

Since the thread (or may be several threads) initiated by *psql.exe* got aborted, certain operation(s) (performed by those threads) must not have completed. If that is the case, then it might be a serious issue.

Any idea, what should be done in this scenario? How to verify whether that error affected anything or not?

Comment: You almost certainly have hook libraries installed that're injecting themselves into some or all of the programs running on the machine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Would write an answer if I had more detail on hand. IIRC Windows lets you register DLLs that intercept process loading and can inject code. Used by antivirus tools, rootkits, and weird things like webcam drivers. Often buggy, can cause problems especially in code not written to be threaded, and especially code that starts+exits quickly. Maybe autoruns.exe can offer hints, don't remember anymore. Last dealt with it in a buggy Logitech webcam driver 10 years ago.